# call function in extjs class dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, dynamic-dispatch

I have an ExtJs class that looks like this:

```
Ext.define("RuleExecutor", {
    singleton: true,
    displayMessage: function(msg) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Popup Message', msg[0]);
    },
    disableById: function(field) {
        Ext.getCmp(field).setDisabled(true);
    },
    //more functions are here...
});
```

Now I get a string => `str` which contains the method name I need to run. I need to call the method in RuleExecutor **specified by the string in str**

**The method is called correctly**, but the arguments are not passed.

Like this:

```
//arguments is an array
function RunRule(str, arguments) {
  //I tried this....
  var fn = RuleExecutor[str];
  fn(arguments)

  //This doesn't work either..
  RuleExecutor[str].apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: It's a singleton, so RuleExecutor.displayMessage('blabla') should work? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Where do you call `RunRule()`?  I don't know if something else applies for ExtJs, but by convention, function names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Now I see `The method is called correctly...`. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define("RuleExecutor", {
        singleton: true,
        displayMessage: function (msg) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Popup Message', msg[0]);
        },
        disableById: function (field) {
            Ext.getCmp(field).setDisabled(true);
        }
    });

    var str = 'displayMessage';
    RuleExecutor[str](['bar']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use 'arguments' as a variable name. There already is a built-in array-like object called '[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)' in JavaScript. Your method may look like this:

```
function RunRule(str) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    RuleExecutor[str].apply(RuleExecutor, args);
}
```

I used the `slice` method from the 'real' array prototype. The line:

```
args = slice.call(arguments, 1)
```

copies all arguments except the first one to the `args` variable. You call `RunRule` like this:

```
RunRule("displayMessage", "Hello");
```